# SQL query that finds a negative change between two rows with the same name field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a single table with rows like this: (Date, Score, Name)
The Date field has two possible dates, and it's possible that a Name value will appear under only one date (if that name was recently added or removed).

I'm looking to get a table with rows like this: (Delta, Name), where delta is the score change for each name between the earlier and later dates. In addition, only a negative change interests me, so if Delta>=0, it shouldn't appear in the output table at all.

My main challenge for me is calculating the Delta field.
As stated in the title, it should be an SQL query.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Show us data, please.  Does "The Date field has two possible dates" mean two possible dates _per Name_ or that every Date attribute is one of two values?

Comment: The problem was already solved, but what I meant was that the date in a given table has only two possible values (which aren't known in advance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed that each name can have it's own start/end dates. It can be simplified significantly if there are only two possible dates for the entire table.

I tried this out in SQL Fiddle **[here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f599db/10/0)**

```
SELECT (score_end - score_start) delta, name_start
FROM
( SELECT date date_start, score score_start, name name_start
  FROM t t
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
  ( SELECT 1
    FROM t x
    WHERE x.date < t.date
     AND x.name = t.name
   )
 ) AS start_date_t
JOIN
( SELECT date date_end, score score_end, name name_end
  FROM t t
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
  ( SELECT 1
    FROM t x
    WHERE x.date > t.date
      AND x.name = t.name
   )
 ) end_date_t ON start_date_t.name_start = end_date_t.name_end
 WHERE score_end-score_start  < 0
```

Comment: That's perfect! It also probably made my life easier in the long run with the assumption you've made. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have a table with `date_value, sum_value`
Then it should be something like that:

```
select t.date_value,sum_value, 
    sum_value - COALESCE((
        select top 1 sum_value 
        from tmp_num
        where date_value > t.date_value 
        order by date_value 
        ),0) as sum_change
from tmp_num as t
order by t.date_value
```

Answer (score 0):

The following uses a "trick" in MySQL that I don't really like using, because it turns the score into a string and then back into a number.  But, it is an easy way to get what you want:

```
select t.name, (lastscore - firstscore) as diff
from (select t.name,
             substring_index(group_concat(score order by date asc), ',', 1) as firstscore,
             substring_index(group_concat(score order by date desc), ',', 1) as lastscore
      from table t
      group by t.name
     ) t
where lastscore - firstscore < 0;
```

If MySQL supported window functions, such tricks wouldn't be necessary.